# Яндекс.Карты API. Создание кластера с использованием geoQuery(json)

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Всем добрый день.
Может быть кто-то сможет подсказать, как я могу создать кластеризатор на карте вот такого вида https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_create, но используя geoQuery(json), где подгружается файл с JSON-массив, вида (это фрагмент для одной точки, такие точки создаются по мере наполнения базы):

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
    "type": "[[+tv.mark_type]]",
    "coordinates": [
        [[+tv.coord_shirota]],
        [[+tv.coord_dolg]]
    ]
},
"properties": {
    "balloonContentHeader": "[[+tv.balloonContentHeader]]",
    "balloonContent": "[[+tv.balloonContent]]",
    "balloonContentFooter": "[[+tv.balloonContentFooter]]",
    "hintContent": "[[+tv.hintContent]]"
},
"options": {
    "preset": "[[+tv.preset]]"
}
```

},

Создать кластер через .clusterize() у меня получилось, но хотелось бы иметь возможность более тонкой настройки, которую дает создания "функция-конструктор" ymaps.Clusterer

Пример одной из попыток вывода:

```
jQuery.getJSON('[[~75]]', function (json) {
  clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
    preset: 'islands#invertedblueClusterIcons',
    groupByCoordinates: false,
    clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
    clusterHideIconOnBalloonOpen: false
  });
  var myGeoObjects = ymaps.geoQuery(json)
  .addToMap(map).applyBoundsToMap(map, {
    checkZoomRange: true
  });
  clusterer.add(myGeoObjects);
  map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
});
```

В результате объекты не собираются в кластер.

Comment: Получайте данные из файла через _$.getJSON_ и добавляйте их в цикле, дописывая любые нужные properties. 
Вот [тут](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_geojson) что-то подобное делается

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но в примере нет кластера и яндекс показывает, как циклом присвоить иконку для каждой точки, потому что в файле с базой у них иконка не прописана. У меня проблема только с обработкой свойств кластера. Вот его иконку присвоить не могу, все примеры подразумевают создание функции ymaps.Clusterer, а у меня с ней уже не работает карта.

Comment: Не могу здесь пример с кодом вставить читабельно. Поправил сообщение с вопросом, добавив пример.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, в итоге с консолью и вашим примером смог добиться нужного результата.